# Can't use logging in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, logging, log4j

i am using the following libraries for logging:

- **slf4j-api 1.6.4**
- **slf4j-log4j12 1.6.4**
- **commons-logging 1.1.1**

and my **log4j.properties** file:

```
log.dir=logs
rrd.dir=${log.dir}/rrd
datestamp=yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS
roll.pattern.hourly=.yyyy-MM-dd.HH
roll.pattern.daily=.yyyy-MM-dd


log4j.rootLogger=ON

log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${datestamp}} [%t] %-5p %m%n



log4j.appender.myFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myFileAppender.DatePattern=${roll.pattern.hourly}
log4j.appender.myFileAppender.File=${log.dir}/MyAPP.log
log4j.appender.myFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.myFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${datestamp}} [%t] %-5p %m%n


log4j.logger.com.myapp=DEBUG, myConsoleAppender, myFileAppender
```

in the **jsp page** i do the following:

```
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.logging.*"%>

<%

        Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

        log.debug("login page");
```

**NOTE:** logging is working fine in java classes.

please advise why it's not working, thanks.

Comment: are you getting any exception. It logging is working in servlet or any other class that JSP.

Comment: @Rais Alam, i am not getting any exceptions and logging is working fine in java classes.

Comment: are you using Filter in any of your class? if yes, can I see that?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info is what I meant. never mind. I understand taht you dont use it by your question.

Comment: are you using same technique to log in java classes?

Comment: what is `getClass()` method returning

Comment: it returns `org.apache.jsp.mail.mypage_jsp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i just added the following line to **log4j.properties** and it works fine now:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.jsp=DEBUG, myConsoleAppender, myFileAppender
```

Answer (score 1):

To use logger in the jsp file, initialize the logger object in the following way:

```
<% Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()); %>
```

Comment: It worked for me too, but still have no idea why I can't log with `"custom.name.jsp"` instead of `this.getClass()`

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other custom tag library, you must properly configure it for your web application. This means putting the log.tld file into the WEB-INF directory and installing the Log tag JAR file into the WEB-INF/lib directory. You will also need to add the appropriate taglib element to your web application's deployment descriptor, similar to how you added the Struts tag libraries:

**Web.xml**

```
<taglib>
<taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/log.tld</taglib-uri>
 <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/log.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

**in your JSP,**

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/log.tld" prefix="logger" %>

<logger:debug message="This is a debug message from a jsp using the Log tag" />

<html> 
   <head> 
       <title>Using the Log Tag in a JSP page</title> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
       <logger:info message="This is another message using the log4j tag" />

         There should be two log messages in the log4j log file. 
   </body> 
</html>
```

This approach is much cleaner with a larger and more complex JSP page

Answer (score 0):

1- in your configurationFile:log4j.xml 
 `<logger name="processus.jsp">
   <level value="info" />
   <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</logger>`

2- in the page JSP:
  `<%@ page import="org.apache.log4j.Logger"%>

<%  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( "yourPage.jsp" );  %>`

Answer (score -1):

Its best to make a logger class in java that will initialize logging.

See [this link](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=491) for java class. Call its logDebug() method from JSP to log messages like `LogClassName.logDebug("message here");`

Comment: You're advocating verbose overkill. Why is it better to create methods for calling the log object than it is to just call the logger object methods directly as needed?